# Can't install ReactiveUI from nuget packages in Visual Studio for mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, system.reactive, reactiveui, visual-studio-mac

When I'm trying to install ReactiveUI version 8.3.1.

The redlined error is

> Couldn't add the ReactiveUI

This is the output after trying to install the package.

```
Total number of results gathered : 173
Gathering dependency information took 10.87 sec
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
/Users/tornike/Desktop/gobatumimobile/packages  -   1.1 sec
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -   2.01 min
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'ReactiveUI.8.3.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Circular dependency detected 'ReactiveUI 8.3.1 => System.Reactive 3.1.1 => System.Reactive.PlatformServices 4.0.0 => System.Reactive 3.1.1'.
```

I'm trying to install it into Xamarin-IOS project.
My Xamarin-iOS version is 11.12.
My Visual Studio for Mac version is 7.5.

I've also tried old versions of ReactiveUI but the result is always same.

How can I solve this problem and install ReactiveUI in my project?
Thanks.

Comment: The ReactiveUI package is kind-of broke in terms of the new `System.Reative` 4.0 packages (which are under a lot of changes)  Install `System.Reactive` 3.1.1 ***first*** and then install the ReactiveUI package. I would highly recommend staying away from System.Reactive 4.0 until ReactiveUI supports it properly (there is an open GitHub issue concerning this...)

Comment: @SushiHangover - When you confirm that this is the answer you should post it as such.